# Заменить <p class="wp-caption-text"> на <div class="wp-caption-text"

Tags: wordpress

В WP под картинкой выводится подпись.
Но она заключена в тег `<p>` а мне очень нужно чтоб она была в `<div>`

Пример:

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">any-content<p>
```

Нужно:

```
<div class="wp-caption-text">any-content<div>
```

Варианты с jquery шоткодами не хотел бы использовать, в силу некоторых причин.

Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
function filter_ptags_on_capt($content)
{
    return preg_replace('/<p class="wp-caption-text">(.*?)<\/p>/', '<div class="wp-caption-text">$1</div>', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_capt');
```

Не работает..
Может быть я ошибся в регулярном выражении, а может оно так не работает в принципе, не пойму в чем затык.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочее решение.

```
function filter_wp_caption_div( $content ) {
    return preg_replace(
        '/<p[^>]+class="wp-caption-text"[^>]*>(.+)(?=<\/p>)/s',
        '<div class="wp-caption-text">\1</div>',
        $content
    );
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_wp_caption_div', 12 );
```